# console.error() throwing undefined error after upgrading angular dependencies from 1.5 to 1.7?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined

Recently I have upgraded angular dependencies from angular 1.5.0 to angular 1.7.0 and after that I am getting undefined error on below code.

```
var error = 'some value';
console.error(error);
```

I an getting undefined error in second line.
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: should it be `var error = 'some value';`?

Comment: yes , sorry my bad..

Comment: can you post your entire code, this has nothing to do with angularjs and can't be breaking the expected behavior

Comment: Can you add a print screen of the error from console?